# GAE datastore index not getting created

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm struggling with the GAE Guestbook demo app. I have made NO modification. I got it running locally, but when I deploy it, I get the following error:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc

The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="Greeting" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="date" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

When running locally, a datastore-indexes-auto.xml was generated in the target/--SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-generated directory. This file contained exactly the required index description:

```
<datastore-indexes>
  <!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
  <datastore-index kind="Greeting" ancestor="true">
    <property name="date" direction="desc" />
  </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

However, the app throws the error above anyways.

I also tried to move it from the auto generated xml file to the manually xml (datastore-indexes.xml) file.

When I deploy via `mvn -e appengine:deploy` I get no error or warning:

```
...
[INFO] GCLOUD: Jan 02, 2017 8:01:14 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Successfully processed /Users/stephanhofmann/Projects/mvntestapp/target/mvntestapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml
[INFO] GCLOUD: Jan 02, 2017 8:01:14 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Successfully processed /Users/stephanhofmann/Projects/mvntestapp/target/mvntestapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml
...
```

Anyways, the Google Developer Console doesn't show any "Composite" Indexes when I check under Datastore > Indexes. I waited for more than 30mins (and there is no data, so indexing should be fast).

Not sure if it is a Composite Index and should show up here, but the App is missing the index and I'm stuck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same problem here. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem when using `mvn appengine:deploy`. Then I realized that I had to use `mvn appengine:deployIndex` explicitly to generate indexes. Hope that helps others.

Comment: Using gradle:  gradlew appengineDeployIndex worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, thanks!  Also, it took about 5 minutes for the Index to get built, even though I only had 1 record/entity in the Datastore DB.  You can watch the status of it building (the Index) via the online web console.

Answer (score 0):

Running:
gcloud app deploy /Users/stephanhofmann/Projects/mvntestapp/target/mvntestapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/index.yaml

In a terminal window will define the indexes.